# gridview rowupdating returns old values

Tags: aspxgridview

I am using a datagrid and using Edit link command. 
I am suppose to take the new values on rowUpdating command and fire it to database. But I am getting only old values. 
I wrote an another page with little functionality, and it is working fine. I am anable to understand what is wrong with my code. I am posting the code below.

Partial Public Class ReferncePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim objBOReferedTable As BO.BOReferedTable
    Dim ObjControllerRelease As Controller.Manager
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        Try
            FillTablesInDropDown()
            BindData()
            'ddl_TableName.SelectedIndex = 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            Common.AlertBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddl_TableName.SelectedIndexChanged
    BindData()
    DirectCast(Master.FindControl("lbl_PageHeader"), Label).Text = "Manage " + ddl_TableName.SelectedItem.Text.ToUpper + " Table"

End Sub

Private Sub dgv_RefTables_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles dgv_RefTables.RowCancelingEdit
    dgv_RefTables.EditIndex = -1
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub dgv_RefTables_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgv_RefTables.RowCommand
    Try
        If e.CommandName.ToUpper = "ADD" Then
            Dim txt_DispSeq As TextBox = DirectCast(dgv_RefTables.FooterRow.FindControl("_txtDispSeq"), TextBox)
            Dim txt_Name As TextBox = DirectCast(dgv_RefTables.FooterRow.FindControl("_txtName"), TextBox)
            Dim Chk_IsActive As CheckBox = DirectCast(dgv_RefTables.FooterRow.FindControl("_chkIsActive"), CheckBox)
            objBOReferedTable = BO.BOReferedTable.getInstance
            With objBOReferedTable
                .Name = txt_Name.Text
                .DisplaySequence = Convert.ToInt32(txt_DispSeq.Text)
                .IsActive = Chk_IsActive.Checked
                .AddedBy = CType(Session("UserProfile"), BOUserProfile).UserProfileId
                .ChangedBy = .AddedBy
            End With
            Dim ctrl As New Controller.Manager
            ctrl.AddToReferedTable(objBOReferedTable, ddl_TableName.SelectedValue)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Common.AlertBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub dgv_RefTables_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles dgv_RefTables.RowEditing
    dgv_RefTables.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindData()
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_RefTables_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles dgv_RefTables.RowUpdating
    Dim row As GridViewRow

    row = DirectCast(dgv_RefTables.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)
    Dim lbl As Label = CType(row.FindControl("lblID"), Label)
    Dim txtDispSql As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("txtDispSeq"), TextBox)
    Dim txtName As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("txtName"), TextBox)
    Dim chkActive As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("chkIsActive"), CheckBox)



    objBOReferedTable = BO.BOReferedTable.getInstance()
    With objBOReferedTable
        .AddedBy = CType(Session("UserProfile"), BOUserProfile).UserProfileId
        .ChangedBy = .AddedBy
        .DisplaySequence = Convert.ToInt32(txtDispSql.Text)
        .Name = txtName.Text
        .IsActive = chkActive.Checked
        .ID = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text)
    End With

    Dim ctrl As New Controller.Manager
    ctrl.UpdateReferedTableData(objBOReferedTable, ddl_TableName.SelectedValue)
    '     dgv_RefTables.EditIndex = -1
    'BindData()

End Sub

Private Sub BindData()
    Dim ctrl As New Controller.Manager
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = ctrl.SelectReferedTableData(ddl_TableName.SelectedValue)
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        Dim BlankRow As DataRow
        BlankRow = dt.NewRow
        BlankRow.Item("IsActive") = False
        dt.Rows.Add(BlankRow)
    End If
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        dgv_RefTables.DataSource = dt
        dgv_RefTables.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillTablesInDropDown()
    Dim Ctrl As New Controller.Manager
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = Ctrl.SelectAllReferenceTable()
    ddl_TableName.DataSource = dt
    ddl_TableName.DataTextField = "DisplayName"
    ddl_TableName.DataValueField = "TableName"
    ddl_TableName.DataBind()
End Sub
```

End Class

my aspx class looks like this..

--%>
      --%>

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_TableName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
      <%-- Style="left: 409px; position: relative;
        top: -174px"AutoPostBack="True">--%>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="308px" Style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" Width="701px" ScrollBars="Auto">
        <%--<table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="center">

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    --%>



<asp:GridView ID="dgv_RefTables" runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          DataKeyNames="ID" 
          ShowFooter="True" 
          OnRowCommand="dgv_RefTables_RowCommand" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="None" Width="916px" AllowPaging="false" PageSize="5" CellSpacing="1">
```

'>

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Order" 
                   SortExpression="DisplaySequence">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblDispSeq" runat="server" 
           Text='<%#Eval("DisplaySequence") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDispSeq" runat="server" 
             Text='<%#Bind("DisplaySequence") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtDispSeq" runat="server" >
</asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME" 
                   SortExpression="Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" 
           Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" 
             Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="_txtName" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTIVE" 
                   SortExpression="IsActive">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_IsActive" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text=""
           Checked='<%#Eval("IsActive") %>'>
</asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIsActive" runat="server"  
             Checked='<%#Bind("IsActive") %>'>
</asp:CheckBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="_chkIsActive" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBox>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks and regards,
Tanmay.

Answer (score 1):

Try with session handling to populate data for postback process

Answer (score 0):

just set Enableviewstate property to false of gridview you can get new value

Reference:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/139076/not-getting-new-entered-values-on-grid-view-row-up
(i got answer)